# Can't edit pom.xml in eclipse JEE

Tags: json, xml, rest, jersey, jax-rs

I want to edit pom.xml ( remove the comments to allow dependencies of JSON response to be used).

But every time I edit it, it returns to it's state...

What should I do?

Thank you

By the way I'm using JAX-RS and Jersey library ( with maven)

Comment: Is it from target folder?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to edit pom.xml [...] But every time I edit it, it returns to it's state...

Looks like you are editing the wrong `pom.xml` file. Ensure that you edit the one that is right under the root folder of your project.